# Not getting email from LinkedIn Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the Objective C library for LinkedIn and trying to fetch user's primary emailId.
I am doing following :-

1)**https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_emailaddress** >> Passing this as the url while requesting for request token.

2) And **http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,industry,email-address)** while fetching profile for user but
I never received email address.

Can you please let me know, what am I missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to put scope parameter in a different way by using OARequestParameter class object which result in success, thus asking me to authorize access to email. However once i submit my credentials, it results in request failure for this url :- http://linkedin_oauth/success?oauth_token=521a8e93-55eb-4777-807c-3f7ab8d30c18&oauth_verifier=10787. giving me error "Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted".

Answer (score 3):

I am able to get the email address successfully. Only change was in the request method for requestToken to pass the scope parameter while requesting for permission in a different way not described in the reference guide on LinkedIn developer page.
Its in "RDLinkedInEngine.m" file >> "sendTokenRequestWithURL:token:onSuccess:onFailure" method >>

```
OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"scope" value:@"r_basicprofile+rw_nus+r_emailaddress"];
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameParam, nil];
[request setParameters:params];
OARequestParameter * scopeParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameterWithName:@"scope"
value:@"r_emailaddress r_fullprofile rw_nus"];
[request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scopeParameter]];
```

Make sure that while requesting for access token , you keep the method as it is provided by default because the same method is used to get request token as well as access token.